# Which one of the following functions has a discontinuity in the second derivative at x = 0, where x is a real variable?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Which one of the following functions has a discontinuity in the second derivative at $x = 0$, where $x$ is a real variable?

(A) $f(x)=|x|^3$

(B) $f(x)=x|x|$

(C) $f(x)=\cos(|x|)$

(D) $f(x)=|x|^2$

Comment: What have you tried? People are more likely to answer your question if you show you have put in some effort yourself first

Answer (score 1):

For (A) show: $f''(x)=6|x|$ for all $x$.

For (B) show: $f'(x)=2|x|$ for all $x$. The second derivative of $f$ does not exist in $x=0$

(C): we have $f(x)= \cos x$ for all $x$. Why ? Hence no problems with $f''$.

(D): we have $f(x)= x^2$ for all $x$. Why ? Hence no problems with $f''$.

Comment: can you please explain why derivive of x|x| is 2|x| and why not 2(x^2)/ |x| thanks

Comment: $ \frac{2x^2}{|x|}= \frac{2|x^2|}{|x|}=2|x|$ for $x \ne 0.$

Comment: thank you very much